# How start program local with data from external server linux

Tags: linux, emacs, x11

In my University we writing in server is located in University(we have acces via ssh).

I use Ubuntu on my laptop so I have the same program like on server.

At home I have low speed internet and when i want to send program by X server it take some time to run it. Is some way to start program for example emacs from my computer(it starts immediatly) and recive only data from server?

Answer (score 1):

*In general*, you might use `sshfs` or similar to mount a remote filesystem so that your local applications can access the files. SSH port forwarding may be useful if you need access to more than just files.

For *Emacs specifically* (it's not clear whether this is the only use-case for your question) you can either:

a) ssh into the remote host, and run `emacs -nw` to run a remote instance of emacs in your terminal. This is *vastly* more network-efficient than running a remote GUI emacs with a local X display. This approach is also good if you already have a running Emacs server on that remote host, as you can connect to it efficiently with `emacsclient -nw`

b) Start a local emacs instance and use the standard `tramp` library to access the remote files.

e.g. <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd> `/ssh:you@hostname:/path/to/file` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Tramp is excellent, so you should spend some time reading about it.

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(tramp) Usage` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for help. This was very helpful. This server where I'm writing logout after 20 minuts when it is unused then my emacs(tramp) hangs up. Could you help me with this? Second question is can i open something(doxygen file - html) by the browser in similar mode(like tramp)?

Comment: `(tramp) Frequently Asked Questions` suggests using a `ServerAliveInterval` declaration in your local `~/.ssh/config` file for the host in question.

Comment: If your other question was "do other applications provide a Tramp-like feature" I can only suggest reading the documentation for those applications. As I said at the beginning, sshfs and/or ssh port forwarding can facilitate generic access to remote resources.

Comment: I wanted to open html file from server with local internet browser. And thak you very much becouse emacs working now is nicer than ever.